# Is implementing IEnumerable required to use foreach on collections?

Tags: c#, loops, collections, iterator

I have the following class that doesn't implement `IEnumerable` but is working perfectly with `foreach`.
And also, arrays are working without implementing `IEnumerable`.

So why does it keep saying that `IEnumerable` needs to be implemented in collections to use with `foreach`. I'm confused, please assist me.

```
class Parent
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
        public void GetData()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("parent");
        }
    }



Parent[] p = new Parent[3]
    {
        new Parent(){MyProperty=90},
        new Parent(){MyProperty=50},
        new Parent(){MyProperty=100}
    };


foreach (var item in p)
    {
        Parent it = item;
        Console.WriteLine(it.MyProperty);
    }
```

Comment: @MasonWheeler corrected

Comment: @RoshanFernando: p is an array in your example, and arrays does implement IEnumerable.

Comment: @DavidPacker Thanks. could you please elaborate your answer by providing a simple example. items in P means properties or what

Comment: @DavidPacker "You must implement the IEnumerable interface if you want to call foreach on your class directly." no, this is not true. Read my or MetaFight's answer

Comment: @kai Perhaps saying must implement is not correct per say, but it's not wrong either. Implementing the interface forces you to implement the `GetEnumerator` method which is required for foreach. Naturally, you can add the method to the class without implementing the IEnumerable interface, but the interface makes it explicit (and there is really nothing wrong with that).

Comment: @DavidPacker If you can use `foreach` without implementing the interface, then saying that you must implement the interface to use `foreach` is objectively false. This is basically akin to saying that you can only `await` `Task`s or that you can only use LINQ queries with `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`. Just because they are the most common doesn't mean that it has to be that way.

Comment: @kai I removed the comment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) looks straightforward to me:

> The `foreach` statement repeats a group of embedded statements for each element in an array or an object collection that implements the `System.Collections.IEnumerable` or `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` interface.

Note that [kai's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/323259/6605), backed by the C# Language Specification, shows that the documentation is too restrictive: it is not necessary to implement one of those interfaces in order to use a class with a `foreach`. Those are implementation details which are interesting by themselves, but irrelevant for your original question, since in your sample code, you're actually using an `IEnumerable`.

What happens is that the sequence you use is an array, and, [according to the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx), emphasis mine:

> Array types are reference types derived from the abstract base type `Array`. **Since this type implements `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`**, you can use `foreach` iteration on all arrays in C#.

Similarly, you could look at [the definition of the `Array` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public abstract class Array : ICloneable, IList, ICollection, 
    IEnumerable, IStructuralComparable, IStructuralEquatable
```

See the `IEnumerable` among the interfaces?

More interestingly, exploring the result of `typeof(int[])` gives you this list for `ImplementedInterfaces` property:

- `typeof(ICloneable)`
- `typeof(IList)`
- `typeof(ICollection)`
- `typeof(IEnumerable)`
- `typeof(IStructuralComparable)`
- `typeof(IStructuralEquatable)`
- `typeof(IList<Int32>)`
- `typeof(ICollection<Int32>)`
- `typeof(IEnumerable<Int32>)`
- `typeof(IReadOnlyList<Int32>)`
- `typeof(IReadOnlyCollection<Int32>)`

where you can see the additional generic interfaces as well. (This also explains why you can write `IList<int> a = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };`.)

Similarly, [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx), [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx), etc. implement `IEnumerable` and `Enumerable<T>`.

So when you say that:

> And also , arrays are working without implementing IEnumerable.

this is simply not true. Arrays *are* implementing `IEnumerable`. As for:

> I have following class that didnt implement IEnumerable but working perfectly with foreach.

it would be interesting to see the actual code (the one you have in your question uses an array). What is probably happening is that your class, without explicitly declaring `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` among its interfaces, implements a more specific interface, such as [`ICollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx), which, in turn, inherits from `IEnumerable`:

```
public interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

And if not, well, you are probably in the case illustrated in kai's answer.

Comment: Please check my code sample above. it is working without IEnumerable

Comment: Thanks yes it s array. Then it is correct. But how we will create a collection without array. (without BCL classes most of them implemented ienumarable)

Comment: *"how we will create a collection without array"*: which one? There are dozens of different sequence-based data structures in .NET. Depending on your actual needs, you may do `new List<int>()`, or `new HashSet<string>()`, or `new Queue<long>()`, or `new Dictionary<string, string>()`...

Comment: Sorry, i m  asking when we need to explicitly implement iIEnumerable because the collections are most of the time arrays or they are already implemented IEnumerable . Can you provide a simple example where we need to implement IEnumerable to iterate.

Comment: @RoshanFernando: when you are creating your own data structure which represents a sequence, such as a linked list (since .NET's `LinkedList<T>` is actually a doubly-linked list).

Comment: @MainMa it is already implemented IEnumterable . so we just need use it in foreach. Im asking when we required to implement IEnumerable explicitly

Comment: @MainMa im awaiting for ur response and  mark this as anwer, can u reply to above commnet

Comment: @RoshanFernando: the one in your previous comment? Not really, since I don't understand your (new) question. Also make sure you read kai's answer as well before choosing which answer to accept.

Comment: @MainMa can you provide a example when we need to implement IEnumterable. Not using BCL libraries , may be using custom object.

Comment: @RoshanFernando: when you need to be able to pass it to the methods which expect `IEnumerable<T>`; it's as simple as that. For instance, if your class only implements [`IEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator(v=vs.110).aspx), you [won't be able to use LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3725269/240613).

Comment: @MainMa well actually ....... you can use LINQ with any type that has instance- or extension methods with the "correct" signature! You can write Select, Where, SelectMany, Join, GroupBy and so on as extension methods on ANY type, and LINQ will magically work, no interface needed! same principle, they couldn't depend on IEnumerable in C# 1 because the language didn't have generics, so they couldn't avoid boxing. With LINQ they found the type system of C# isn't powerful enough to describe monads, so they had to hack it into the compiler. Same deal with Tasks (for other reasons I guess)

Comment: @kai: what I wanted to say is that you can't use the existing LINQ methods without `IEnumerable<T>`. Of course, writing extension methods yourself makes it possible to have a behavior similar to LINQ for anything else, such as `IEnumerator`.

Answer (score 8):

It isn't required. The `foreach` keyword basically just "rewrites" your code so it becomes a while loop calling `MoveNext()` and looking at `Current`, but the interface `IEnumerable` isn't needed. This is backed up by the [C# Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) under section `15.8.4 The foreach statement`

Try compiling the following code and you'll see msbuild has nothing to say about it:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public Foo(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public T Value { get; }

    public FooEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new FooEnumerator<T>(Value);
    }
}

public class FooEnumerator<T>
{
    private bool _hasValue = true;
    private readonly T _value;

    public FooEnumerator(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (_hasValue)
        {
            Current = _value;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            _hasValue = false;
            return _hasValue;
        }
    }

    public T Current { get; private set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        foreach (var x in new Foo<int>(1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
}
```

All that is required to use the `foreach` keyword is that there is a method called `GetEnumerator()` that returns ANY type that has a method called `MoveNext()` returning a `bool` and a property called `Current` (of any type) with at least a visible getter

It works similarly to LINQ query comprehensions. The following code compiles and runs smoothly:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public Foo(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public T Value { get; }

    public Foo<U> Select<U>(Func<T, U> f)
    {
        return new Foo<U>(f(Value));
    }

    public Foo<U> SelectMany<U>(Func<T, Foo<U>> f)
    {
        return f(Value);
    }

    public Foo<V> SelectMany<U, V>(Func<T, Foo<U>> f, Func<T, U, V> g)
    {
        return new Foo<V>(g(Value, f(Value).Value));
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        var result =
            from x in new Foo<int>(5)
            from y in new Foo<int>(9)
            select (x + y).ToString();

        // result is now a Foo<string> containing the value "14"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But could you please answer my question usingthe sample provided.

Comment: The official documentation says it is required. You tell the exact opposite. Can you provide some authoritative source for your claim?

Comment: Added an example of `Foo<T>` being iterable using `foreach` without implementing `IEnumerable`

Comment: @MainMa I think the C# compiler is a pretty good source. My code compiles and runs. You could probably look it up in the language spec also.

Comment: _"result is not a Foo<string>"_ my compiler VS2015 tells me that `result` is a `Foo<string>`. Please check it.

Comment: @marbel82 was a typo

Comment: This is nonsense. "No, you do not have to implement IEnumerable, you only have to implement GetEnumerator". FCOL, that is the very definition of implementing IEnumerable! A class that implements GetEnumerator and returns a functional IEnumerator implements IEnumerable. The ": IEnumerable" behind the class name is just a declaration that gives you some type safety.

Answer (score 7):

Eric Lippert actually has a piece about this:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern/

Eric's explanation:

> What is required is that the type of the collection must have a public method called GetEnumerator, and that must return some type that has a public property getter called Current and a public method MoveNext that returns a bool.

Interestingly (and as the article goes on to mention) this is a relic of C# 1.0's lack of generics.  The C# compiler used Duck typing to allow Enumerators to return the appropriate type for the collection instead of returning `Object` and incurring boxing/unboxing costs for value types.

I remember learning about this when I was still in university and learning C#.  It made me feel icky at the time.  Now I find it kind of clever!

Comment: I agree, I found it distasteful when I first saw it as well. But after having to actually deal with the realities of retrofitting new features into old languages with real-world libraries that have multiple inconsistent coding patterns, suddenly this sort of duck typing becomes really attractive.